# ClassCastException for casting Object[] to Trie.Node<V> but not E[]

Tags: java, arrays, generics, classcastexception

In the past, I've been able to implement a generic ArrayList by casting Object[] to E[]:

```
public class ArrayList<E>
{
    private E[] elements;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList()
    {
        elements = (E[])new Object[16];
    }
 }
```

and I could use the generic array normally, like so:

```
public void add(E element)
{
    ...
    elements[size++] = element;
}
```

I thought I could implement a trie similarly:

```
public class Trie<V>
{
    private static class Node<V>
    {
        public V value;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Node<V>[] next = (Node<V>[])new Object[26];
    }

    private Node<V> root = new Node<V>();
}
```

However, the line `public Node<V>[] next = (Node<V>[])new Object[26];` in Trie.Node causes a ClassCastException:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Trie<Integer> t = new Trie<Integer>();
    }
}

java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LTrie$Node;
    at Trie$Node.<init>(Trie.java:6)
    at Trie$Node.<init>(Trie.java:3)
    at Trie.<init>(Trie.java:10)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

So it's saying I can't cast Object[] to Trie.Node[].

What's the difference between casting from Object[] to E[] and casting from Object[] to Trie.Node<V>[]? Why is the former permitted and not the latter?

Comment: Please improve your accept rating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that generics are implemented via erasure, and giving no bounds will erase that generic type into `Object`. `E[]` will become `Object[]`, while `Trie.Node<V>[]` will become `Trie.Node<Object>[]`. Hence, `(Node<V>[])new Object[26];` is a invalid cast as you're trying to cast `Object[]` to `Node<Object>[]`.

You can find more information about how erasure works at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html.

Comment: `Trie.Node<V>[]` will become `Trie.Node[]`

Answer (score 2):

```
public Node<V>[] next = (Node<V>[])new Object[26];
```

should be changed to

```
public Node<V>[] next = (Node<V>[])new Node[26];
```

or even

```
public Node<V>[] next = new Node[26];
```

as the cast is not checked anyway and both forms require `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: Does `Node` without the type parameter (`Node<V>`) simply mean `Node<Object>`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this question earlier. No, these are not the same. Using Node<Object> instead of Node would not compile since a Node<Object> is not a Node<V>. Using just node, you simply prevent the type checking. This is generally not a good idea, but works here because initially all the elements are null, and thus can be cast to any type, and you're only adding Node<V> elements, so won't get a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

`Node<V>[]`  array is not `V[]` It works in first case because Type information is E is available and ArrayList is uses Strong Typing.

So if you remove generics form picture what you are doing is casting `Object[]` to `Node[]` which will result in class cast exception.

You might want to use `V[]`

```
public V[] next = (V[])new Object[26];
```

More information available on [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html.)